# LIKE query in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, wildcard, where-clause

I am not getting the desired results with the following query that uses LIKE. Can I use the WHERE clause?

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET ALPHA = 'ABC'
WHERE ALPHA LIKE 'ABC%' 

UPDATE TABLE
SET ALPHA = 'ABCCC' 
WHERE ALPHA LIKE ‘ABCC%'


Bt90Abc Abc
bt91Abc Abc
bt19abcCC      ABCCC
bt16abcSTAT ABC
```

Comment: Please specify your Problem, what results are you excepting?

Comment: I want bt90abc to be abc, bt91abc to abc, bt19abc to be abccc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement to perform the update:

```
update yourtable 
set alpha = case 
              when alpha like '%abcc%' then 'ABCC'
              when alpha like '%abc%' then 'ABC'
              else alpha
            end
where alpha like '%abc%';
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d36fb/1).

This will update any rows that match the criteria in the `LIKE` with your values.  If it does not, then the `alpha` value will not be updated.

Comment: The `or alpha like '%abcc%'` can be removed. It can be true only if `alpha like '%abc%'` is true. Check this **[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5542/1)**

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory glance it appears you could have two standout issues here.

-String comparisons are case sensitive and you are searching for uppercase letters while it may contain lower case ones. Try throwing an UPPER around your column in the where clause.

-Secondly, it appears you are searching strings for ABC that do not start with ABC. In this condition you should use '%ABC%' as your where clause.

For better input you should provide more information about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your comments:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET ALPHA = CASE WHEN ALPHA IN ('bt90abc','bt91abc') THEN 'ABC' 
                 WHEN ALPHA IN ('bt19abc')  THEN 'ABCCC'
            ELSE ALPHA END
WHERE ALPHA IN ('bt90abc','bt91abc','bt19abc')
```